# Perl: hash feeded in a for loop, is empty outside the loop

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm stoke with an understanding of the HASH functionality. With a “for” loop, I create hashes and “hashnames” dynamically and I'm feeding them with some key/values elements. Unfortunately, these values are not anymore visible outside the loop.
Below the small code I'm using and their output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use English;
use Data::Dumper;

@wA = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");
@dA = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

for (my $i=0; $i<=$#wA; $i++){
    $hn = "hash-$wA[$i]";
    push(@hna, $hn);
    %hn = ();
    #my %hn;
    $hsize = @hn;
    print "1. HashName: " . $hn . " Size: " . $hsize . "\n";
    print "HashName: $hn\n";
    if ($i == 0){
        print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
        for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
            $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
            print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    if ($i == 1){
        print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
        for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
            $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
            print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    if ($i == 2){
        print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
        for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
            $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
            print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    if ($i == 3){
        print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
        for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
            $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
            print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    if ($i == 4){
        print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
        for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
            $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
            print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    if ($i == 5){
        print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
        for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
            $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
            print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    if ($i == 6){
        print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
        for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
            $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
            print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    @hk = keys %hn;
    $hsize = @hk;
    print "2. HashName: " . $hn . " Size: " . $hsize . "\n";
}

print "\n";
print "Araay with hashNames: " . @hna . " Array length: " . $#hna . "\n";
print "\n\n\n";

print "Hash info out of the FOR loop\n";

for (my $k=0; $k<=$#hna; $k++){
    @hnaca = keys %{$hna[$k]};
    #@hnaca = keys @{ @hna[$k] };
    #@hnaca = keys \%{ $hna[$k] };
    #@hnaca = keys %{ $hna->[$k] };
    print "Element: " . $k . " HashName: " . $hna[$k] . " Size(\$#): " . $#hnaca . " Size(\@): " . @hnaca . "\n";
}
```

And the output is like below:

```
1. HashName: hash-a Size: 0
HashName: hash-a
Feed the hash hash-a: 1 => a, 2 => b, 3 => c, 4 => d, 5 => e, 6 => f, 
2. HashName: hash-a Size: 6
Data::Dumper: 1. HashName: hash-b Size: 0
HashName: hash-b
Feed the hash hash-b: 2 => b, 3 => c, 4 => d, 5 => e, 6 => f, 
2. HashName: hash-b Size: 5
Data::Dumper: 1. HashName: hash-c Size: 0
HashName: hash-c
Feed the hash hash-c: 3 => c, 4 => d, 5 => e, 6 => f, 
2. HashName: hash-c Size: 4
Data::Dumper: 1. HashName: hash-d Size: 0
HashName: hash-d
Feed the hash hash-d: 4 => d, 5 => e, 6 => f, 
2. HashName: hash-d Size: 3
Data::Dumper: 1. HashName: hash-e Size: 0
HashName: hash-e
Feed the hash hash-e: 5 => e, 6 => f, 
2. HashName: hash-e Size: 2
Data::Dumper: 1. HashName: hash-f Size: 0
HashName: hash-f
Feed the hash hash-f: 6 => f, 
2. HashName: hash-f Size: 1
Data::Dumper: 
Araay with hashNames: 6 Array length: 5



Hash info out of the FOR loop
Element: 0 HashName: hash-a Size($#): -1 Size(@): 0 -> expected 5 / 6
Element: 1 HashName: hash-b Size($#): -1 Size(@): 0 -> expected 4 / 5
Element: 2 HashName: hash-c Size($#): -1 Size(@): 0 -> expected 3 / 4
Element: 3 HashName: hash-d Size($#): -1 Size(@): 0 -> expected 2 / 3
Element: 4 HashName: hash-e Size($#): -1 Size(@): 0 -> expected 1 / 2
Element: 5 HashName: hash-f Size($#): -1 Size(@): 0 -> expected 0 / 1
```

How can I get the expected values?

Comment: There is a great deal wrong with your program in addition to the answer you have accepted, but it is very hard to understand what you're trying to do, and indeed, what *"the expected values"* might be. You need to start by adding `use strict` as well as `use warnings 'all'`; surely you've seen advice to do that on *every* Perl program you write? But if you explain better what you are aiming for then you will get much better help

Comment: You appear to be doing something horrible [this article](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) explains why using a variable as a variable name is nasty. You should also note - `$hn` and `%hn` aren't in any way related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your program is that you are not saving your hashes at all. `push(@hna, $hn);` pushes the name of the hash as a string to `@hna`. This is the only variable you save for the outside of your `for`.

If you save both the name, and the hash you create in `@hna` like this: `push(@hna, {name => $hn, hash => \%hn});` you will have more success.

```
 @@ -9,9 +9,7 @@ use Data::Dumper;

  for (my $i=0; $i<=$#wA; $i++){
      $hn = "hash-$wA[$i]";
 -    push(@hna, $hn);
 -    %hn = ();
 -    #my %hn;
 +    my %hn = ();
      $hsize = @hn;
      print "1. HashName: " . $hn . " Size: " . $hsize . "\n";
      print "HashName: $hn\n";
 @@ -73,6 +71,7 @@ for (my $i=0; $i<=$#wA; $i++){
      }
      @hk = keys %hn;
      $hsize = @hk;
 +    push(@hna, {name => $hn, hash => \%hn});
      print "2. HashName: " . $hn . " Size: " . $hsize . "\n";
  }

 @@ -83,9 +82,9 @@ print "\n\n\n";
  print "Hash info out of the FOR loop\n";

  for (my $k=0; $k<=$#hna; $k++){
 -    @hnaca = keys %{$hna[$k]};
 +    @hnaca = keys %{$hna[$k]->{"hash"}};
      #@hnaca = keys @{ @hna[$k] };
      #@hnaca = keys \%{ $hna[$k] };
      #@hnaca = keys %{ $hna->[$k] };
 -    print "Element: " . $k . " HashName: " . $hna[$k] . " Size(\$#): " . $#hnaca . " Size(\@): " . @hnaca . "\n";
 +    print "Element: " . $k . " HashName: " . $hna[$k]->{"name"} . " Size(\$#): " . $#hnaca . " Size(\@): " . @hnaca . "\n";
  }
```

This gives this full program, which works for me:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w

 use warnings;
 use English;
 use Data::Dumper;

 @wA = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");
 @dA = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

 for (my $i=0; $i<=$#wA; $i++){
     $hn = "hash-$wA[$i]";
     my %hn = ();
     $hsize = @hn;
     print "1. HashName: " . $hn . " Size: " . $hsize . "\n";
     print "HashName: $hn\n";
     if ($i == 0){
         print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
         for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
             $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
             print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
         }
         print "\n";
     }
     if ($i == 1){
         print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
         for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
             $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
             print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
         }
         print "\n";
     }
     if ($i == 2){
         print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
         for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
             $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
             print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
         }
         print "\n";
     }
     if ($i == 3){
         print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
         for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
             $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
             print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
         }
         print "\n";
     }
     if ($i == 4){
         print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
         for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
             $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
             print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
         }
         print "\n";
     }
     if ($i == 5){
         print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
         for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
             $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
             print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
         }
         print "\n";
     }
     if ($i == 6){
         print "Feed the hash $hn: ";
         for (my $j=$i; $j<=$#dA; $j++){
             $hn{ $dA[$j] } = $wA[$j];
             print "$dA[$j] => $wA[$j], ";
         }
         print "\n";
     }
     @hk = keys %hn;
     $hsize = @hk;
     push(@hna, {name => $hn, hash => \%hn});
     print "2. HashName: " . $hn . " Size: " . $hsize . "\n";
 }

 print "\n";
 print "Araay with hashNames: " . @hna . " Array length: " . $#hna . "\n";
 print "\n\n\n";

 print "Hash info out of the FOR loop\n";

 for (my $k=0; $k<=$#hna; $k++){
     @hnaca = keys %{$hna[$k]->{"hash"}};
     #@hnaca = keys @{ @hna[$k] };
     #@hnaca = keys \%{ $hna[$k] };
     #@hnaca = keys %{ $hna->[$k] };
     print "Element: " . $k . " HashName: " . $hna[$k]->{"name"} . " Size(\$#): " . $#hnaca . " Size(\@): " . @hnaca . "\n";
 }
```

Comment: Bolav, thanks for your fast solution and the explanation.

Comment: @stevieb I'm not going to force anyone to use strict.

Comment: Not using `strict` is ok. Not using `strict` and then asking for free help when your code doesn't work - especially when it's things that `strict` would have caught, is just rude.

Answer (score 2):

Curiously, is this what you're after?:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @wA = qw(a b c d e f);
my @dA = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6);

my %hash;

for my $w (@wA){
    $hash{$w} = shift @dA;
}
```

...or using the iterator (it's rare we need iterators in Perl). Note the use of the `..` aka. flip-flop operator or officially the [range](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) operator:

```
for my $i (0..$#wA){
    $hash{$wA[$i]} = $dA[$i];
}
```

...or even a tiny bit more succinctly (without the explicitly defined iterator):

```
for (0..$#wA){
    $hash{$wA[$_]} = $dA[$_];
}
```

...in the end, you could even end up with this (so long as you've pre-checked the length of each array):

```
for (@wA){
    $hash{$_} = shift @dA; # requires array length checks
}
```

...one more (suggested by @Borodin that I neglected), a [*slice*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices):

```
@hash{@wa} = @dA
```

Then, in all above cases, use `Dumper`, or:

```
for my $key (keys %hash){
    print "$key: $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

Comment: Or even `@hash{@wa} = @dA`

Comment: ohhhh nice. Forgot about that one ;)

Comment: Your link was to `splice`, which is different from `slice`. Fixed.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Nice catch.

Comment: I was also thinking of writing `$hash{shift @wA} = $_ for @dA;`, but I was hoping to be reasonably understandable. Odd thing is, is that I spent two months writing a new module and was using `slice` and `splice` unforgettably... yet this one eluded me :)

Comment: Perhaps `$hash{$wA[$_]} = $dA[$_] for 0 .. $#wA` which is better as it's non-destructive. TMTOWTDI indeed!